# Is there a way I can use an Interceptor in NHibernate 4.0 with stateless session?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a big pre-exisiting project which was using NHibernate 2 with stateless session which used interceptors for altering values before CRUD operations (eg: timestamps of insert/update/ecc.); now after upgrading to NHibernate 4 I see that there is a design choice to not call interceptors for stateless sessions and I can't find a workaround, has anyone faced a problem like this and may there be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Event Listeners](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html) instead. Ayende wrote a [post](https://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener) in his blog about this.

Comment: Even I thought about that but I've seen that stateless does not fire events too:http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.html  "... A regular NHibernate ISession keeps a lot of data in its first-level cache (this enables a lot of the NHibernate magical goodies). The IStatelessSession however, does no such thing. It does no caching whatsoever and it also doesn't fire all of the events that you could usually plug into. This is strictly meant to be used for bulk data operations. ..."